# Criterion for $F:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ to be a contraction map

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

So I've got the function $F:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by 
$$F(\vec{x}) = A\vec{x} +\vec{b}$$

and I'm trying to figure out a "simple condition" on the entries of $A$ such that $F$ is a contraction. This is an exam revision question so I've got the final answer which is $a_{11}^2+a_{12}^2+a_{21}^2+a_{22}^2 = \lambda <1$ but I haven't been able to figure out how to get that. The question also asks to do this using Holder's inequality.

I tried working with a supposed fixed point, $\vec{z}$, and then substituting into contraction mapping inequality so that

$$\left| A\vec{z}\right|\leq \lambda \left| \vec{z} \right| $$

But I didn't get anywhere with that. Hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you are working with the euclidean norm $\|\cdot \|_2$. Then $F$ is a contraction iff the 2-norm of the matrix $A$, i.e. $\|A\|_2$, is less than $1$, where 
$$\|A\|_2= \max_{\|x\|_2 = 1} {\|Ax\|_2}.$$
Now it can be seen that $\|A\|_2^2$ is the largest eigenvalue of the positive-semidefinite matrix $A^*A$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) for details).

Note that 
if $x=x_1e_1+x_2e_2$ and $\|x\|_2=1$ then
$$\|Ax\|_2^2=\|x_1\,Ae_1+x_2\,Ae_2\|_2^2\leq\left(|x_1|\,\|Ae_1\|_2+|x_2|\,\|Ae_2\|_2\right)^{2}\\ \leq\|x\|^2(\|Ae_1\|^2_2+\|Ae_1\|^2_2)=a_{11}^2+a_{12}^2+a_{21}^2+a_{22}^2,
$$
where we used the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).
Hence $$\|A\|_2^2\leq a_{11}^2+a_{12}^2+a_{21}^2+a_{22}^2$$
and we may conclude that if $a_{11}^2+a_{12}^2+a_{21}^2+a_{22}^2<1$ then $F$ is a contraction.

However there are contractions such that $a_{11}^2+a_{12}^2+a_{21}^2+a_{22}^2>1$. For example take
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0.6 & 0.6\\0 & 0.6 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: That's an interesting linear algebra approach to it, but do you have any clues as to how you can do this using Holder's inequality?

Comment: @Excalibur42 I added a few details. Here we need Cauchy-Schwarz inequality (a particular case of Holder's)

Comment: @Excalibur42 Any further doubts?

Comment: Ah okay great, I see that now. I didn't make the link between Holder's inequality and Cauchy-Schwarz, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A direct calculation, though essentially the same as that of Robert's:

$$ \|Ax\|^2 = \sum_i \left( \sum_j a_{ij} x_j \right)^2
  \leq \sum_i \left( \sum_k a_{ik}^2 \sum_\ell x_\ell^2\right) = \sum_{i,k} a_{ik}^2 \sum_\ell x_\ell^2 = \lambda \|x\|^2 $$

Answer (score 0):

In case you're working Euclidean norm you can impose following assumption  on entries of $A$, 
$$\|A\|_{\max}  < \frac{1}{2} $$

Where $\|A\|_{\max}$ indicates the largest absolutvale of entries!

Note that $\|A\|_2 \leq 2 \|A\|_{\max}$

Comment: Norm isn't specified in the question so I'll assume Euclidean. Not sure why this bound helps though?